# Bash/GitBash: Regex comparison doesn't work inside aliases

Tags: bash, alias

As stated in Q-title, I have an alias setup for running multiple Git commands if the current directory in GitBash terminal is valid Git repository.

Now I am trying to do a regex comparison of User prompt's answer such that if User types `y` or `Y` then it must go ahead and run the command after the next `&&` like below:

```
alias abc="([ `git rev-parse --git-dir` == \".git\" ] && git restore \"*lock*\" \"*mix-manifest*\" && git status && (read -p \"Run 'git diff'? \" && [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] && git diff))"
```

But this alias when called throws the following error:

```
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `^[Yy]$'
```

And from this bit-vague error message, I got that the problem is somewhere in `[[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]` and maybe because I am using this comparison inside double-quotes of an alias. I already tried replacing `^[Yy]$` with `'^[Yy]$'` and `\"^[Yy]$\"`, but in vain.

Can anyone assist in figuring out the problem in `[[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]` and fix this ?

Comment: What about create a bash file into your local bin dir and call it from your alias ?

Comment: `$REPLY` is substituted before the alias is assigned, so you're effectively getting `[[ =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]` assuming REPLY is empty. Try replacing the alias with a function, it will be much easier to write the code you want without dealing with parsing rules.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of nice suggestion by @tjm3772, I was able to fix this by **converting the alias into function** as below:

```
abc(){ ([ `git rev-parse --git-dir` == ".git" ] && git restore "*lock*" "*mix-manifest*" && git status && (read -p "Run 'git diff'? " && [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]] && git diff)); }
```

And declaring this in `.bashrc` file, and it worked like charm.